# Identificar que campos se modificaron al actualizar un formulario y guardarlos

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Tengo un formulario que lo actualizo, pero me gustaría saber de que forma podría identificar que campos fueron los que se modificaron de forma especifica. Luego de eso guardarlos para que mas adelante puedan ser tomados en cuenta en una ponderación.

En donde a cada usuario se le reste un punto por cada modificación.

He intentado hacer una comparación antes de actualizar los datos y los que resulten diferentes entonces guardarlos en otra tabla que solo contendrá las modificaciones especificas. Aun no me ha funcionado del todo bien y creo que se podría hacer de una forma mas eficiente.

De esta forma en mi metodo update verifico los cambios y los guardo:

```
$facturaModificada =  new Modificacion;

    if($factura->documento != $request->documento){
        $facturaModificada->save();
    }
```

Comment: Pero entonces solo es ver cuáles cambiaron y/o almacenar eso en otra tabla?

Comment: Si, he modificado la pregunta para que sea mas clara.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes utilizar [`isDirty()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#examining-attribute-changes). Primero guardas los cambios en el modelo.

```
$factura = find($request->id)->fill($request->all());
```

Posterior a eso, verificas si hubo algún cambio utilizando dicho método:

```
if($factura->isDirty()){
     // Obtienes los cambios y creas el nuevo registro
}
```

Si no quieres utilizar `fill`, puedes hacerlo manualmente:

```
$factura->atributo = $request->atributo;
...
$factura->save();
```

**Nota:** No usar el método `update()` para usar `isDirty()`.

Si quieres revisar cuáles son los cambios, puedes obtenerlo mediante `getChanges()`:

```
$factura->getChanges();
```

Y crear el nuevo registro con los cambios:

```
if($factura->isDirty()){
     Modificacion::create($factura->getChanges());
}
```